# Grails standalone container performance

Tags: grails

I have a question about the performance of grails running a standalone container.

When I run `./gradlew bootRun` my application responds 454413 in one minute. When I compile the application using `./gradlew war` and run `java -Dgrails.env=prod -server -Xmx2048M -jar build/libs/g6-app-0.1.war` the same application only responds to 3132 requests in one minute.

I don't understand what it could be.

Grails 6.0.0
JVM java 20.0.2
Container Undertow